# No g++ is found after installing a g++ package in Cygwin

Tags: g++, cygwin, mingw-w64

I have installed `mingw64-x86_64-gcc-g++` package in Cygwin. However, `which g++` does not show any installed `g++`. Where is the installed  compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/bin/g++` is part of the `gcc-g++` package.

`/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++` is part of the `mingw64-x86_64-gcc-g++` package.

[Example](//github.com/svnpenn/glade/blob/503aabb/fdk-aac/makefile#L16-L17)